# How to generate CSR file from custom config using azure?

Tags: azure, csr

I have custom configuration file for openssl, I want to generate CSR using this file in azure?. and also I want to generate private key.

```
oid_section = OIDs
[OIDs]
certificateTemplateName = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2
[req]
default_bits = 2048
emailAddress = MyEmail@email.com
req_extensions = v3_req
x509_extensions = v3_ca
prompt = no
default_md = sha 256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn
[dn]
C=SA
OU=Riyad Branch
O=Contoso
CN=EA123456789
[v3_req]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment
[req_ext]
certificateTemplateName = ASN1:PRINTABLESTRING:PREZATCA-Code-Signing
subjectAltName = dirName:alt_names
[alt_names]
SN=1-TST|2-TST|3-ed22f1d8-e6a2-1118-9b58-d9a8f11e445f
UID=310122393500003
title=1100
registeredAddress= MyAddress
businessCategory=Industry
```